# Employee seems to be overwhelmed and delegating work to others

Tags: management

On multiple occasions, I am noticing that an employee is delegating work to others that should technically be his responsibility, rather than asking his direct supervisor for help.

I think that he may be overwhelmed which is why he is delegating the work.

Should I wait until I have proof of what he is doing before I speak to someone about it? Who would be the right person to discuss the situation with without making that employee feel bad that they aren't doing the work themselves.

Comment: Do you mean "delegating" (passing off to another) rather than "relegating" (moving to a lower rank, which doesn't really make sense)?

Comment: Also, please [edit your question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/190966/edit) to include your role here - are you the employee's supervisor/manager, a member of their team or just a bystander?

Comment: If you aren't the person being delegated to, keep your nose out of it; this is between the parties involved and the manager. If you are, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Evan summing up the comments before, we need this info to give better answers: (1) are you this person's manager? (2)Are you an equal or member of the same team? (3) Are you completely unrelated and just noticed this? (4)Are you one of the persons being delegated to?

Comment: I'm going to VTC, as it's pointless soliciting answers without knowing your role here.

Comment: The question seems legitimate, but there is far too little information provided to properly understand the situation and advise about it.

Comment: It isn't clear the question is legitimate. Flipping it around, the problem may be that the person seems overloaded because they aren't delegating _enough_....

Answer (score 3):

> Should I wait until I have proof of what he is doing before I speak to someone about it? Who would be the right person to discuss the situation with without making that employee feel bad that they aren't doing the work themselves.

It would greatly help us if you disclosed your role on the company, as the answers depend where are you and this employee relative to each other on the hierarchy of the company. Meanwhile I'll try to answer the best I can:

First thing that comes to mind is that **if this employee is delegating tasks, then it implies that they have the authority/power to do such thing** (otherwise they wouldn't be able to delegate them). It also implies in a way that this person is handing tasks to his/her subordinates (as it is unlikely that they are handing such tasks to his/her manager/boss), or the very least to their equals/peers (case where those equals/peers could say no to the request).

Under that scenario (again, we need more info to better help you), this seems normal to me: *a person delegating tasks when overburdened to their subordinates/lower ranks.*

Now, realistically, if you are an equal or below this person then you should not be focusing on why this person is delegating tasks, as it is *not* your role to manage or supervise them. That's a role their manager should be doing. You do you and focus on doing a good job.

If you are this person's manager, then you are in a good position to speak to them directly and ask for clarification so you can sort things out. If you are higher up in the chain (and it is your role to worry about these things), then a good point to start could be to reach out to this person's manager and ask about the situation (just be sure you aren't micromanaging ;).

Again, if you are an equal/peer or lower in the ranks this is not your business and I suggest you focus on doing your job and tasks actually assigned to you.